# Facebook chat for android

Tags: facebook, chat

http://credentiality2.blogspot.com/2010/03/xmpp-asmack-android-google-talk.html

Can i use this code for facebook chat ???

Comment: Since Facebook chat uses the XMPP protocol, you can probably adapt it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has released some [notes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) for developers, which Google also [has](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html). Skim through the Facebook information. You will most likely be able to use smack/asmack for most of the protocol, though I imagine Facebook has made some proprietary additions/changes.

Comment: I used this code and changed the settings for Facebook chat but and exception raisea says, not connected to the server

Comment: You should elaborate by posting some code to show how you incorporated the Facebook API Key and the Facebook SASL authentication. I'd be willing to bet one of these locations is where your issue lies.